# How can I find the units digit of $2^{11213}-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: in 1963 mathematicians at the University of llinois used a computer to show that $2^{11213} -1$ is prime. this number has 3376 digits in base 10. what is the units digit?

I haven't learned any modular arithmetic or Euler's function. I've been given this as a bonus problem in my precalculus class. I was thinking that I could look for some repeating patters for the last digit with powers of 2.

$2^1=2$

$2^2=4$

$2^3=8$

$2^4=6$

$2^5=2$

So it repeats every 4 powers. However I do not know what to do from here or if i'm on the correct track

Comment: That's a good start.  Can you use it to, say, predict the last digit of $2^{100}$ ?  What about $2^{237}$?  Once you get the hang of it, you'll manage $2^{11213}$.

Comment: Also means $2^k+2^{k-1}$ has the same remainder on division by 10 as $2^{k+2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So it repeats every 4 powers.

Yes!!!!!!!

> However I do not know what to do from here

Oh no!!!!

> or if i'm on the correct track

You are *SOO* much on the right track that if you don't get up and jump under that train, I'll pick you up and throw you under!  And .... oh, wait.... that's not a very encouraging metaphor at all!

....

Okay, you are *soooo* close.

If it repeats every $4$ powers you have the last digit of $2^k$ is the same last digit of $2^{k+ 4}$ is the last digit of $2^{k+8}$ is the same last digit of ....  $2^{k + 4m}$.... for any $m$.

And so because $11213 = 4*2803 + 1$ then $2^{11213} = 2^{1+4*2803}$ will have the same last digit as $2^{1+4*2802}$ has the same last digit as $2^{1+4*2801}$ has ..... the same last digit as $2^{1+4*3}$ has the same last digit as $2^{1+4*2}$ has the same last digit as $2^{1 + 4}$ has the same last digit as  $2^1$.

So the last digit of $2^{11213}$ is $2$ and the last digit of $2^{11213} -1$ is $1$.

Comment: ah thank you for such an easy to understand explanation!!

Answer (score 2):

You're on the correct track.  Likewise, you could say $2^{11213}=2\times(2^4)^{2803},$ and $2^4$ ends with $6,$ and powers of numbers ending with $6$ always end with $6$, so $2\times(2^4)^{2803}$ ends with $2$, and that prime ends with $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the exponent is at form $4k+1$. So what is the unit of power?

From the pattern you found, $2$, right?

So, the unit of the number is $2-1=1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to prove that $$2^{4k+1}\equiv2\pmod{10}\\2^{4k+2}\equiv4\pmod{10}\\2^{4k+3}\equiv8\pmod{10}\\\\2^{4k}\equiv6\pmod{10}$$
Then, since $11213=4k+1$ the power $2^{11213}$ has last digit $2$ and  $2^{11213}-1$ has $\color{red}1$ as unit digit.

Comment: "I haven't learned any modular arithmetic"

Comment: Then "the last digit is repeated each four times".